# spool with column headers in pipe delimited sqlplus

Tags: sql, sqlplus, spool

I currently am spooling a pipe file via this sqlplus script:

```
    set feedback off
    set echo off
    set verify off
    set pagesize 0
    set heading off
    set termout off
    set trim on
    set wrap on
    set trimspool on
    set linesize 9000
    spool c:\exp3.txt
    select
    to_char(D_DTM, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24.mi.ss')||'|'||
    DAYOFWEEK||'|'||"24HOUR"||'|'||TECHNOLOGY||'|'||VOICEDATA||'|'||MRKT_NM||'|'||REGION_NM||'|'||CLUSTER_NM||'|'||
    CLUSTER2_NM||'|'||BSC_NM||'|'||BTS_ID||'|'||BSC_BTS||'|'||CSCD_ID||'|'||CSCD_NM||'|'||SECT_SEQ_ID||'|'||BND_ID||'|'||
    FA_ID||'|'||ATT_CNT||'|'||AXS_F_CNT||'|'||CE_BLK_CNT||'|'||CUST_BLK_CNT||'|'||DRP_CALL_CNT||'|'||HHI_ATT_CNT||'|'||
    HHI_BAFRM_CNT||'|'||HHI_CALL_SETUP_SXS_CNT||'|'||MBL_ORG_CNT||'|'||MBL_TER_CNT||'|'||NON_BTS_EQ_BLK_CNT||'|'||
    PRIM_CALL_ERL||'|'||PWR_BLK_CNT||'|'||SFUL_CALL_CNT||'|'||SILENT_RETRY_CNT||'|'||T1_BHL_BLK_CNT||'|'||WCD_BLK_CNT||'|'||
    SMS_ATT_CNT||'|'||SMS_SXS_CNT||'|'||CTRL_CH_USG_CNT||'|'||CTRL_SL_USG_CNT||'|'||DO_SECT_PHL_FWD_PS_TMS||'|'||
    DO_SECT_PHL_REV_PS_TMS||'|'||EUSR_CONN_SETUP_ATT_CNT||'|'||EUSR_CONN_SETUP_F_CNT||'|'||FWD_D_TRANSD_QTY||'|'||
    MAC_ID_BLK_CNT||'|'||MAC_ID_UTIL_RT||'|'||MS_RQST_CNT||'|'||MS_RQST_D_QTY||'|'||NORM_CONN_CLS_CNT||'|'||
    NORM_SESS_RLS_CNT||'|'||RAB_SET_CNT||'|'||RCVD_RAB_CNT||'|'||REV_AIR_PER_BAD_FRM_CNT||'|'||REV_AIR_PER_TRSF_D_QTY||'|'||
    REV_D_TRANSD_QTY||'|'||RNC_BLK_CNT||'|'||SESS_ATT_CNT||'|'||SESS_CONF_SXS_CNT||'|'||SL_USG_CNT||'|'||MAX_USER_CNT||'|'||
    AVG_USER_CNT||'|'||MOU_TMS||'|'
    from ds3r_fh_all_fa_lvl_kpi
    where D_DTM = to_date('8/19/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

but I can't figure out how to include the column names as the header in the file as well. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `pagesize` to a non-zero number that way your headers will be displayed. The number you set it to may depend on the number of rows that you have. If you set it 100 as per the following line:

`set pagesize 100`

then 100 rows will be printed under the headers, then the column headers will be repeated for the next 100 rows. The maximum as mentioned in 50000. Also set `heading` to on as

`set heading on`

otherwise it will not display the headers, despite the pagesize being non-zero. Also remember when you are selecting columns in that way they will not be padded, so the headings might appear out of place.

Answer (score 10):

```
set heading on
set pagesize 0 embedded on
```

- Includes header
- Infinite page size

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest you a smarter solution because I have been working on this for a moment. Instead of making appearing the header which for me is not a very nice solution, you can create it from your own text.
Simply adding a SELECT and UNION will do this nicely :

```
SELECT 'CHANNEL_CODE ; ISDN ; ACTIVATION_DATE ; TOTAL_MONEY ' from dual
union all
SELECT * ... (your query here)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

setting pagesize to 0 turns off the column headers in sql*plus.

try setting it to 50000

```
set pagesize 50000
```

I think that's the max (I may be wrong on that!)

Answer (score 0):

Below setting at the top of the .sql file works.

set pagesize 50000
set heading on

Answer (score 0):

set pagesize 0 embedded on

add above line after spool